# Unity 3D Set object in cone

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to place an object at a specific position relative to another :

[image]

This new object has to be placed in the pink zone, and I only know the minimum and max distance of placement, an angle relative to my first object forward direction (maxAngle in degrees), and the position of this first object.

I already know how to check if an object is placed in the pink zone, but not set its position in this zone. So I took the code to check an object in the cone, but I can't get how to transform it to set the position in the cone.

```
float distance = Random.Range(minDistance, maxDistance);
float angle = maxAngle *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;
float coneRadius = distance * Mathf.Tan(angle);

Vector3 vect = firstObject.transform.position - targetObject.transform.position;
targetObject.transform.position = new Vector3(angle, 0, firstObject.transform.position.z + distance);
```

If you can give me clues, it'll be very cool.

Comment: Do you have the middle vector?

Comment: The first objet is not moving/rotating, so it's the perpendicular axis.

Comment: So you have a direction vector and position and a maximum and a minimum distance, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I know all of that, and also the angle in degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The trick is to move the *local* position and then straighten...

This is indeed a basic technique in Unity or any transform-based scene engine.

Create the new object, "newb".

(1) Position the object exactly at the "+" in your image.

(2) Choose your angle

```
   angle = Random.Range(-maxAngle, maxAngle);
```

(3) Twist newb by that much:

```
   newb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3( 0f, 0f, angle);
```

(4) Choose your distance:

```
     distance = Random.Range(minDistance,maxDistance);
```

(5) Then offset the ***LOCAL*** position of newb by that much:

```
     newb.transform.Translate(0f, 0f, distance, Space.Self);
```

And then the trick:

Note that "newb" will be "twisted", so make it sit straight:

```
       newb.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, I'm not looking how to rotate the object I've to create, I want to place it in a precise angle from the relative object, the problem is not the distance because the compute is pretty simple, but the distance with the angle, because the position has to be set in a cone shape.

Comment: I didn't noticed the translation, sorry ! It works fine, thank you.